# Is there any (performance-related) downside to compiling C code with the Visual Studio C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

This is my first time developing with Visual Studio (2010) and I noticed that:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int) * 50);
```

gives an error when I try to build "main.c". I'm assuming this is because VS is using its C++ compiler to build C programs.

Is the code generated by VS for C as good as it gets under Windows or should I look for something better and/or exclusive to C?

Comment: VS uses its C++ compiler to build C++, and its C compiler to build C programs. You just have to tell it what you want to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the Visual Studio compiler purely because it's not C99 compliant, and I find C99 much easier to work with.

Personally I use MinGW + GCC instead, but I use Notepad++ instead of Visual Studio.  I know that its definitely possible to get Visual Studio to compile using GCC, but I'm not aware of anyone who has done this yet.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm assuming this is because VS is using its C++ compiler to build C programs.

Your assumption is incorrect:  there is nothing wrong with that line of code and in fact Visual C++ will compile it without error:

```
c:\dev>type stubby.c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int) * 50);
}

c:\dev>cl stubby.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

stubby.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:stubby.exe
stubby.obj

c:\dev>
```

Whether Visual C++ is suitable for your needs depends on what your needs are.  It does not support C99; if support for C99 is important to you, then you'll want to find another compiler.  It does not support the plethora of GNU language extensions; if those are important to you, you'll want to find another compiler.

Comment: The program does build and run, however, the word "malloc" is underlined in red and the tooltip reads: Error: A value of type void* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type int*. C++ is the language with strong type checking, not C. So VS must be using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Carlos:  The IntelliSense squiggles have many false positives; I do not know whether they are supposed to support C.  They do not in any way affect the Visual C++ Compiler, which uses a completely different compiler frontend from the IntelliSense engine.

Answer (score 1):

1. This has nothing to do with performance; it's a language restriction. In C++, you need a cast:

   ```
   int *x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 50);
   ```
2. There are other compilers for Windows than the Visual C++ compiler; take a look at G++ (part of [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), for example.
3. In general, C compilers can optimize better than C++ compilers can. But I don't think using the same exact compiler in C++ mode makes any difference than running it in C mode, at least not typically.

Comment: That cast that you're suggesting should be done differently in C++.  C-style casts are pure evil, unless your code is in C.

Comment: @GregC: Agree that it should be C++-style. Disagree that C casts are "pure evil". :\

Comment: @GregC: I don't? Why would I just search for a random cast?

Comment: Hav e aread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593137/tool-for-finding-c-style-casts

Comment: @GregC: I took a quick glance at it, and it doesn't tell me *why* I would just need to "search for C-style casts". If I'm looking for a *particular* cast (like `(int*)`), then I just search for that... but searching for a random cast seems a bit, er, random. I don't really see what's wrong here, and I've never had trouble with C-style casts; could you explain a bit more?

Comment: From my experience with C++ on embedded systems, it's very hard to spot incorrect casts that result in memory overruns.  C++ has introduced static_cast<> that is enforced by compiler.  For the above case, a static cast is inappropriate -> raising a red flag when somebody reads the code with reinterpret_cast<>.

Comment: @GregC: I don't work on embedded systems, so I don't have that kind of experience. From my work on regular PCs, though, I can say that (1) I *very rarely* do potentially dangerous pointer casts in the first place (with a notable exception being on things like `malloc`), and (2) for other casts, I don't really see what's wrong -- it's not like casting a `long` to an `int` is "bad" with C-style casts anyway.

Comment: @GregC: Admittedly interesting cases, but admittedly, those are just *examples*, not really real-world code. For downcasts (and possibly upcasts) in a class hierarchy, you obviously use `dynamic_cast`, so it's not like I'm arguing for C-style casts there. But for other kinds of casts, C-style casts don't seem to be "dangerous" in terms of behavior -- they do exactly what you expect, don't they? Is there a good reason why I would bother casting the result of `malloc` with anything other than a C-style cast?

Comment: In the original example, you have used type int thrice.  Relationship between int* local variable and (int*) c-style cast is checked by the compiler to ensure same size of pointer field at assignment.  The third mention of int is used for arithmetic only, and isn't verified by compiler.  reinterpret_cast<> makes such code more discoverable, so that programmer can focus on this spot if there's a real problem with the allocated buffer size.

Comment: @GregC: I don't understand -- what does `reinterpret_cast` have *anything* to do with `sizeof(int)`? And doesn't your link say `reinterpret_cast` is just as "bad" as a C-style cast?

Comment: Exactly.  This is a point where compiler has to make assumptions -- therefore it needs to be checked extra carefully by dev.  Other places, with dynamic_cast<> and static_cast<> are better covered by runtime type id and by compiler.  Allows dev to focus on the hot spot.

Comment: @GregC: Wait, what? When was the last time you ran into a casting bug with `malloc`? Certainly hasn't ever happened to me... I don't see why I need to type 14 more characters for a piece of code that's probably never going to turn out wrong (certainly hasn't happened yet, anyway).

Comment: Good discussion on taxonomy of casts!  I'll see you tomorrow.

Comment: This example does not lend itself very well, because int follows size_t.  What if we changed the code to read as follows: word *x = (word*)malloc(sizeof(word) * 50);  Then introduce a bug: size_t *x = (size_t*)malloc(sizeof(word) * 50);  This works on a 16-bit platform, but randomly crashed at runtime on a 32-bit platform, in other people's code.  Compiler is oblivious all along.